# Pandas: add offset to date when DST changes

Tags: python, pandas

I'm not sure if this is a pandas bug or if I'm doing something wrong.

Given a datetime like this:

```
foo_date = pd.Timestamp('2016-10-30 00:00:00', 
                        tz=pytz.timezone('Europe/Helsinki'))
```

And an interval offset (`'D'`, `'10m'`, whatever), I want to get the start date of the next interval.

I do it this way:

```
offset = pd.tseries.frequencies.to_offset('D') # 'D' or any other offset, it shouldn't matter
new_date = foo_date + offset
```

Or like this (same result):

```
offset = pd.DateOffset(1)
new_date = foo_date + offset
```

I'm expecting this:

```
Timestamp('2016-10-31 00:00:00+0200', tz='Europe/Helsinki')
```

But instead, I'm getting this:

```
Timestamp('2016-10-30 23:00:00+0200', tz='Europe/Helsinki')
```

The problem is that `2016-10-30` is a 25 hours day, due to the DST change, so when I add `offset`, it only adds 24 hours and I'm getting the wrong datetime.

I think time offset should be timezone-aware, but it seems they're not. How can I achieve what I need?

Comment: Curious to know what is that +03:00 and +02:00

Comment: Is the timezone offset. `13:00:00+03:00` is `10:00:00` in UTC.

Comment: Does someone know if there is already a solution to this issue?

Comment: Not really, but check this thread: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16980